# Latest version of MS Visual Studio Code freezes on starting

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code on a Linux CentOs. I am unable to use the latest version. With them as soon as I launch the program it opens up the previous window but immediately freezes; after a while the Linux pop-u windows appears asking me for a force-quit.

I am wondering if something something is corrupted in the VSC caches. Where is it located on Linux?

By the way the latest version that works is 1.52.1.

Thanks
Maurizio

Comment: which version freezes, in a month the latest is a different version

Comment: At least with this tar file I have the freeze issue: code-stable-x64-1620838810.tar.gz